# Ordering factor vector with another factor vector

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am struggling plotting my data with ggplot in the desired order. Her is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
library(tidyverse)

# the data
fruits <- tibble(
    type   = factor(c("apple", "orange", "banana", "melon", "cherry", "unknown")),
    year   = c(2010, 2010, 2012, 2010, 2010, 2012),
    size  =  factor(c("XS", "S",  "M", "S", "S", "M")),
    weights = rnorm(6, as.numeric(size) + 2)
)

# the plot
fruits %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = type, y = weights, fill = size)) +
  geom_col()
```

Now I want that the fruits that have the same size are next to each other in the plot, i.e. order the type by the size. Any idea how to do that? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do the reordering of 'type' based on the 'size' column and then plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

fruits %>%
    mutate(type = factor(type, levels = as.character(type)[order(size)])) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = type, y = weights, fill = size)) +    
         geom_col()
```

It would also make more sense to have `weights` also in the `order`

```
fruits %>%
   mutate(type = factor(type,
         levels = as.character(type)[order(size, weights)])) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = type, y = weights, fill = size)) +
      geom_col()
```

[image]

---

Or another option is `facet_wrap`

```
fruits %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = type, y = weights, fill = size))  +
     geom_col() +
     facet_wrap(~ size)
```

---

Or another option is `fct_reorder` from `forcats`

```
library(forcats)
ggplot(fruits, aes(x = fct_reorder(type, as.numeric(size)), y = weights)) + 
       geom_col() +
       xlab("type")
```